# react not found component always renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

This is code for looping through routes file. Here i am creating routerconfig array an exporting from here to app.js.

> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react';
> import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
> import routes from './routes';
>
> class RouterConfig extends Component {
>   render() {
>     return (
>       routes.map((route) => {
>         return (
>           <Route
>             key={ route.id }
>             path={ route.path }
>             exact={ route.exact }
>             component={ route.component }
>           />
>         );
>       })
>     );
>   }
> }
> export default RouterConfig;
> ```
>
> This is my route configuration file, where i have listed all routes.
>
> ```
> import Home from '../components/home/home';
> import About from '../components/about/about';
> import Posts from '../components/posts/posts';
> import NotFound from '../components/not_found/not_found';
>
> const routes = [
>   {
>     path: '/',
>     exact: true,
>     component: Home,
>     id: 'home',
>   },
>   {
>     path: '/about',
>     component: About,
>     id: 'about',
>   },
>   {
>     path: '/posts',
>     component: Posts,
>     id: 'posts',
>   },
>   {
>     component: NotFound,
>     id: 'not_found',
>   },
> ];
>
> export default routes;
> ```
>
> This is my app.js 
>       import React, { Component } from 'react';
>       import { Switch, Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
>       import Header from '../header/header';
>       import Footer from '../footer/footer';
>       import history from '../../history';
>       import RouterConfig from '../../router/browserroute';
>
> ```
> class App extends Component {
>   render() {
>     return (
>       <div>
>         <Router history={ history } >
>           <div>
>             <Header />
>             <Switch>
>               <RouterConfig />
>             </Switch>
>             <Footer />
>           </div>
>         </Router>
>       </div>
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> export default App;
> ```
>
> issue is on every page i am getting not found component render. Even
>   using switch with routes not getting the expected results. not sure
>   why code is not working properly.
>
> [this is how it renders not found in every page ][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7evW.png
>
> on changing:
>
> ```
> class App extends Component {
>   render() {
>     return (
>       <div>
>         <Router history={ history } >
>           <div>
>             <Header />
>             <Switch>
>               <Route exact path='/' component={ Home } />
>               <Route path='/about' component={ About } />
>               <Route path='/posts' component={ Posts } />
>               <Route component={ NotFound } />
>             </Switch>
>             <Footer />
>           </div>
>         </Router>
>       </div>
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

This works fine

Comment: I am very surprised that `RouterConfig ` does not throw an error when a `render` attempt is made. Is this a detail you omitted?

Comment: nope haven't omitted any thing, i am using react react-dom version 16.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `Switch` to be inside `RouteConfig`. There must be something with the way React 16 partials work that is unexpected in React Router (I'm not really sure why it does not work when Switch is outside RouterConfig). The good news is, at least for me, it makes sense to be inside RouteConfig.

Here is a codesandbox that works:

https://codesandbox.io/s/8xmx478kq8

Comment: cool glad to know that. don't forget to update this answer as the accepted one so folks know we got a solution for this.

Comment: I followed you example, but the menu appears below the component that is rendered. any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of React are you using? If you are using React 15 or lower, it does not support returning an array inside render. You would need to wrap you stuff in a container.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from './routes';

class RouterConfig extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{
      routes.map((route) => {
        return (
          <Route
            key={ route.id }
            path={ route.path }
            exact={ route.exact }
            component={ route.component }
          />
        );
      })
      }</div>
    );
  }
}
export default RouterConfig;
```

Notice the div wrapping the Routes array

Comment: react react-dom is version 16.0.0, I have tried your suggestion but still its no working

Comment: if you are using 16.0.0 I don't see anything wrong with your stuff, except for the history. How you are getting that created? Check this codesandbox I created, it should work. So I'm assuming it is something with your history implementation that is not detailed in your question. Can you expand the codesandbox so that we can validate? https://codesandbox.io/s/wywn5pn198

Comment: i have made changes you can see in this sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/v30m3m07r0

Comment: why is your history module empty?